# How to make an HTTP Post with the same session ID?

Tags: python, selenium, http, session, post

How can I do to make a HTTP Post request in using the current session ID and HTTPS connection ?

Currently, I do :

```
def postData(product, url, dataToPost): 
    ret_status = False
    session = requests.session()
    try :
        # Open session
        response = session.post(product.get_url("login.htm"), verify = False, data = {"user": product.login, "password": product.password}, timeout = 5000)

        # Send HTTP Post
        response = session.post(product.get_url(url), verify = False, data = dataToPost, timeout = 5000)
        dataJson = json.loads(response.text)
        if(dataJson['status'] == "OK"):
            ret_status = True

        # Close session
        response = session.post(product.get_url("login.htm?logout"), verify = False, timeout = 5000)

    except TimeoutException:
        print("         [timeout] HTTP->sendCmd")
        session.close()
        return False
    except requests.exceptions.SSLError as sslErr:
        print("         [SSLError] HTTP->sendCmd")
        session.close()
        return False

    session.close()
    return ret_status
```

My tests :

```
# Open session
driver.get(product.get_url("login.htm"))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "loginInput")))
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "loginInput")
element.send_keys(login)
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "passInput")
element.send_keys(password)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "submitButton").click()

# Wait index.htm is loaded
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "index_content")))

# Do some test ...

# Send HTTP Post
postData(product, "toto.json", {"key1":"value1"})

# Do some test ...

# Do some test ...



# Close session
driver.get(product.get_url("login.htm?logout"))
```

Problem is when I call postData(), it is open a new session... I want to use the same HTTPS connection and session.
How can I do ?

My web server is in an embedded system and that's why I need to limit number of simultaneous HTTPS connections

Comment: What exactly is your problem? you are creating a session and using it for all your requests. Thats fine

Comment: I updated my message : is it more understandable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create your session at top level and pass it to `postData()`:

```py
def postData(product, url, dataToPost, session):
    # use session here
```

```py
session = requests.session()

# use session here

# Send HTTP Post
postData(product, "toto.json", {"key1":"value1"}, session)

# use session here

session.close()
```